# Removing the front part of a string based on an specific character. (\)

Tags: powershell

I first create my array with a list of files in a directory (and subdirectories) using the Cmdlet Get-ChildItem, and store them in a variable

```
$PSVariable = (Get-ChildItem -Path "F:\SQL_Backups" -Recurse *.bak).FullName
```

I echo the variable ($PSVariable), this is my output (as desired):

> F:\SQL_Backups\INTRAPORTAL\StoreDevelopment\StoreDevelopment_backup_2021_02_11_003002_3930170.bak
> F:\SQL_Backups\INTRAPORTAL\StoreDevelopment\StoreDevelopment_backup_2021_02_12_003002_4780885.bak
> F:\SQL_Backups\JDASQL\DEVMOD\DEVMOD_backup_2021_02_10_190002_5130923.bak
> F:\SQL_Backups\JDASQL\DEVMOD\DEVMOD_backup_2021_02_11_190003_7621021.bak

Goal:
I need to remove the directory path from each array entries so it only contains the file name that will be stored in a temporary variable within a foreach loop:

> StoreDevelopment_backup_2021_02_11_003002_3930170.bak
> StoreDevelopment_backup_2021_02_12_003002_4780885.bak
> DEVMOD_backup_2021_02_10_190002_5130923.bak
> DEVMOD_backup_2021_02_11_190003_7621021.bak

Some will recommend simply using (.Name) in the Get-ChildItem command, but I need the array to have both the path and filename (FullName) as the array's contents are being used for other parts of the function. I'm a novice when it comes to regular expressions and I can't seem to get the results in the goal section. I've even tried using trim() methods, but no luck. Any recommendations would greatly be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: If you must have two separate arrays, why not do 
`$files = Get-ChildItem -Path "F:\SQL_Backups" -File -Recurse *.bak; $fullNames = $files.FullName; $names = $files.Name`

Comment: I still don't know why you can use `$PSVariable = Get-ChildItem -Path "F:\SQL_Backups"  -File -Recurse *.bak | Select FullName,Name,Directory`. Then just use `$PSVariable.Fullname` or `$PSVariable.Name` whenever you need it.

Comment: I apologize for the delayed response (Other projects). What @AdminOfThings recommended resolves my issue. I'm not sure what I thinking initially that cause what I was setting up to spin out of control.

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on what @AdminOfThings recommended, you are making more work for yourself than you need.  PowerShell is an object based scripting language, so to succeed you should use its full POWER.

The approach you're taking now is to take only one property from this useful object and then find you need to start slicing and dicing it in order to make it work.

There's an easier way.  We love easy here, and the easy way to do this is to take the full object and then pick and chose its properties where it makes sense, like this:

```
$i = 0 
#changed to remove the .FullName at then end
$PSVariable = (Get-ChildItem -Path "F:\SQL_Backups" -Recurse *.bak) 
ForEach ($item in $psVariable){
   $i++
   Write-host "Processing [$($item.Name)], item number $i of $($psVariable.Count)"

   Copy-item -Path $item.FullName -Destination C:\temp -WhatIf
}
```

It gives you meaningful output and then you have the full selection of properties to work with.

[image]

The one that makes the most sense to use is just `.Name` as you reference above.  But then you still have `.FullName`, which includes the qualified path as well.

If you want to see the full selection of properties, try this:

`$PsVariable[0] | Format-list *`

Answer (score 1):

Offered only as an inferior option to that of FoxDeploy's you can also use `Split-Path` to get the filename from a path

```
$PSVariable = (Get-ChildItem -Path "F:\SQL_Backups" -Recurse *.bak).FullName
$PSVariable | Split-Path -Leaf
```